# Bootstrap collapsible not working after first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a website using PERSONA as the CMS and am including collapsible elements on the page through Bootstrap. I've included Bootstrap Version 3.3.7 and PERSONA comes with an internal version of Jquery. You can view the website here: 
https://agdraft3.persona.co/

The collapsible part works properly the first time or after a refresh but when I click a link inside of the collapsed elements and then go back, it freezes until I refresh. The only error thrown is one related to the inclusion of a vimeo embed and searching hasn't brought up any results.

Here's my code:

```js
  
  $(document).ready(function(){
     var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      }
    }
    });
```

```css
    button.accordion {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
        color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
        text-align: left;
        outline: none;
        font-size: 15px;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }
    
    button.accordion.active, button.accordion:hover {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    div.panel {
        padding: 0 18px;
        background-color: white;
        max-height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
```

```html
HTML

    <button class="accordion active">
     <h2 class="collapse">Current</h2></button>
      <div class="panel">
       <div class="indent">
        <h2 class="current">
          <a href="Weird-Seeds" rel="history">Weird Seeds</a>
        </h2>
        <h2>(2017)</h2>
        <small>Weird Seeds is a community of artists &amp; scholars who tell stories about ecology, memory, and power.</small>=
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: @ColeGwozdecki please stop editing-in snippet markup where it's not appropriate. Without various extra pieces (jQuery, for example; or the Bootstrap CSS), the snippets are at best non-functional; in this case, all we get is a `$ is not defined` error message (not present in the actual website). Snippets are for HTML/JS/CSS examples that can *run* and *demonstrate the problem* right here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

da,
So to break things down a little cleaner you should separate your HTML/JS/CSS into all separate files.  Then simply inject you CSS via a link tag into your HTML and then inject your JS the same but via a script tag.  This is mostly semantics, but could also be the reason for your error. It does look like you're loading you JS though at the end of your HTML which is good so your HTML has parsed before JS loads.

So I would be that what you're missing is

`<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>`

I couldn't see where jQuery is loaded at all, at looks to be getting confused.  If it works once that would be my guess.

Comment: Cool website too, very creative.

Comment: So I can externalize the CSS but the PERSONA editor comes with a place to add custom CSS. 

Also it doesn't allow any external versions of jquery and immediately comments them out when I try to save them into the custom html

Comment: Are you stuck with the PERSONA editor? Why not use VSCode, so much better and still free.

Comment: I see you are probably using them as a host.  There has to be a way.  But still though the PERSONA jQuery i'd bet is interfering with your Bootstrap.  You're using the CDN for Bootstrap which is causing the confusion, well in a way.  You have figure out how to inject Bootstrap into persona

Comment: It's for a client I'm working for and they pay for this service so I'm stuck using it. 

Though for a second the system glitched out and let me save an external jquery. The collapisble started to work between links but the entire editor broke after that so I had to take it out and now it won't let me readd it.

Comment: I am not familiar with Persona looks very unique but I've never heard of it.  Looks like Persona is the publishing feature of the website and Cargo (https://2.cargocollective.com/) is the editor.  I think you should have access to Cargo.  In Cargo you should see something for settings and/or some level of site admin.  I think that is where it will live for you to inject the bootstrap libraries.  And if those don't work there are a ton of other libraries out there, like Bulma rather new but I think it doesn't require jQuery or SemanticUI  is another.